# Output not showing in For loop

Tags: vector, printing

My code is

```
$PrePrint = If[MatrixQ[#], MatrixForm[#], #] &;

t = {
    {-2,3,0,-3},
    {-1,-2,2,1},
    {-2,0,2,-1},
    {1,-3,1,3}
};

EVt  = Eigenvectors[t]

For[i=1,i<=2,i++,
    Indexed[EVt,i]
]
```

And my output ist.

```
{{-1, 1, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 0}, {(-3 - I*Sqrt[3])/2, (-1/2*I)*(I + Sqrt[3]), (-1 - I*Sqrt[3])/2, 1}, {(-3 + I*Sqrt[3])/2, (I/2)*(-I + Sqrt[3]), (-1 + I*Sqrt[3])/2
```

Note because of the PrePrint it is actually in a "nice" matrix shape. What I now want is, every vector printed on its own. But the For loop just outputs nothing. I'm an absolut beginner in Mathematica so I don't understand, what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell MMA to print a value inside a for loop. And indexing is easily done using `[[...]]`

```
For[i = 1, i <= 4, i++, Print[EVt[[i]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: `Print /@ EVt;` is more straightforward than `For`.

Comment: Thank you for you answers. I have several follow up questions.
1. Using ```Print[EVt[[i]]]``` it only outputs the first two vectors. While ```Print /@ EVt;``` outputs all 4 of them. Why?
2. Using ```Print``` makes them be in the ```{ }``` format like in Daniel Hubers answer. But I'd like them to be in a "nice" Matrix format. How can I achieve that?